# Visual Studio 2008 linker error: ALINK operation failed (80070005) : Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, access-denied

I have Visual Studio 2008 (9.0.30729.1 SP) installed on my computer and a build machine.  On my computer, a project builds fine.  On the build machine, I have started getting this error.
ALINK operation failed (80070005) : Access is denied

This is incredibly irritating because it doesn't say Access TO WHAT??? is denied.

I've tried rebooting the machine, and changing the output directory of the project.
It's a C++/CLI DLL.  The project links with a large number of libraries so it's not really practical to extensively check everything it links with, but a quick scan of the project and nothing seems to be missing or locked.

Anyway I can figure out what the heck linker is complaining about?  Sounds like a bug in the linker(1), but as I said I have the same Visual Studio installed in my PC and the project builds fine.

(1) You could argue that an error message that unhelpful *IS* a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always good to have [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) as a tool in your toolkit:  it can log every file operation, and will help showing *what* exactly the linker wants to do with what file.

(Find it at sysinternals.com)

Comment: That worked.  I used Process Monitor and filtered on link.exe and found a problem in the MS cryptography API which made me realize it is some problem it's having signing my DLL.  If I take out the keyfile I don't get the linker error.  Now I just have to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding administrator access to the "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys" folder.  Not sure how that got screwed up, but whatever.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

In the output window, can you see where it is failing while doing what operation?

Often you might get an error because a file it is trying to modify is under source control / not writeable because of SOME reason.

Also, you might just be missing some file which it is looking for.